# URL rewrite rules are not working

Tags: url-rewrite

I am trying to create custom URL rewrite from category to CMS page.

I have page url like this `about-us.html` as category page and about as CMS page.

Now when i create custom url it works but after the indexing it is not working, it again shows `about-us.html`.

Comment: do you use a link item? if yes then you should change it as well to show the page that you want.

Comment: @Vsld : I couldn't get the terms link item. Can you give the details?

Comment: ok, you want that from through the main menu or any static block? i mean where you click and the redirection being made?

Comment: obviously from main menu. I have menu as category page About-us which is having url as about-us.html. Now i created one CMS page, for that url is about. now redirect about-us.html to about page

Comment: do you use mega menu?

Comment: No. I am using simple menu@Vsld

Comment: then go to your menu settings, into the desired item and set the cms page that you want to be displayed.